# why my background image is not showing online

Tags: html, css, image

my image is not showing on the site. it is not linking. what puzzles me, is that i did a copy/paste of another class in my css file that works, changed the names  and into the html, as i retyped the link, "../images/whatso" etc visual code studio was posting the next folder and file on the path, so the link is valid, but it does not work... it's just html and php, nothing big.

```
    .devant {
        background-image: url("../images/straz/indexpix.jpg") ;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative; 
        text-align: center;
        color: rgb(192, 38, 0);
        background-color: teal; 
        height: 100%;
       
    }
```

html: div class="devant"

Comment: Welcome to SO.  How are you deploying it?  Are you certain that the deployed path of the background is accessible?

Comment: Please check your path once as this can be possible if there is any issue to access the path. Also if you are working online than your code must be on server also check your folder permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to give width and height for background property to work.

```
.devant {
    background-image: url("https://www.flaticon.com/svg/static/icons/svg/141/141944.svg") ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative; 
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(192, 38, 0);
    background-color: teal; 
    height: 80px; /* height of the devant div */
    width: 80px; /* width of the devant div */
   
}
```

Comment: i tried, did not work. i had inside background-size: cover; which had worked for the other one...      .rue {
            background-image: url("../images/straz/rue.jpg") ;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: cover;
            position: relative; 
            text-align: center;
            
            height: 100%;
           
        } so i don't get why not this one

Comment: We have to mention width and height also. like  .rue { background-image: url("../images/straz/rue.jpg") ; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover; position: relative; text-align: center; height: 100%; width: 100%/* mention width also */ }

Comment: ooooh! it comes out on my cellphone, but not on firefox nor chrome ???

Comment: Can you send a screenshot?

Comment: but rue works - always had, that's what's odd, but i will add it too, in case of future bugs lol. i'm too new to know better, thank's !

Comment: rue is in contact

Comment: Inside of rue, there is content. So, it will take width of the content

Comment: Replace this class=" display-5 blanc m-5 p-5 " with class=" display-5 blanc m-md-5 p-5 " and decrease font size also.  .blanc {font-size: 25pt;} and .display-3 {
    font-size: 2rem;

Comment: flops - nope - grr, i can't see why it's not working. i have some content in it, not much but still some. i does work on my cellphone, that's the strange thing !!!

Comment: <div class="devant">
        <h1 class=" display-5 blanc m-md-5 p-5 ">Strasbourg Confinée<hr></h1>
        <h3 class=" display-3 text-light center pb-5 ">Encore plus belle !</h3>
    </div>

Comment: i took out the line strasbourg confiné - the display-5 blanc.

Comment: you have two div's with same class name. (<main class="devant"><div class="devant"></div></main>)

Comment: oui ! lol, i just took it out, thx! still don't work

Comment: how do i add a screenshot here plz?

Comment: i'm sorry to bother you so much with this headache. thx for your time so much !

Comment: You have to use different images for mobile screens and desktop.

Comment: If my answer solves the background image issue, please upvote my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it works - and worked all along i was told- on pc but not on mac. sorry, i was not using the right word - by pc before, i meant computer. silly
so it works on the phone and on pc but not on mac. i don't get why